# chineseFood[array[0]] = array[array.length-1];

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't understand the purpose of this = sign on the sixth line in the code block below. I understand how the argument grabs each index number of the array, I just don't understand why chineseFood[array[0]] = array[array.length-1]; In other words, I don't get the purpose of the equal sign as if it were almost comparing each other to be stored in the empty object that is stored in the variable chineseFood. Could someone please clarify? It would be much appreciated.

```js
function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
  var chineseFood = {};

  //takes 1st element (at index 0) and sets it to the last element (nth index): array(length-1)
  chineseFood[array[0]] = array[array.length - 1];

  return chineseFood;
}

console.log( transformFirstAndLast(['Orange', 'Lemon', 'Pork', 'Chicken']) );
```

Output Below

```
{Orange: "Chicken"}
```

Comment: As far as I can say, it is nothing special, it is just taking the `first element` as the key of **chineseFood** object and `last element` as the value **chineseFood**. and `=` operator for **assignment** of `key=>value` nothing else

Comment: "I don't understand the purpose of this = sign on the sixth line". The `=` is used for assignment, i.e. it's an assignment operator.

Answer (score 4):

The equals sign is not comparison, it is assignment. `chineseFood` is an object, which means that it can be treated like a dictionary, and its properties can be accessed using the `[]` operator instead of the `.` operator:

```js
myObj = {
  foo: "bar"
};
console.log(myObj["foo"]); // bar
console.log(myObj.foo); // bar
```

Likewise, you can also assign properties this way:

```js
myObj = {};
myObj["foo"] = 3;
console.log(myObj["foo"]); // 3
console.log(myObj.foo); // 3
```

This is what your code is doing. It is retrieving the value of `array[array.length-1]`, which is `"Chicken"`. Then it is assigning this value to the property of `chineseFood` that has the name represented by `array[0]`, which happens to be `"Orange"`. Thus, the property named `Orange` on `chineseFood` is set to `array[array.length - 1]`, which is why `chineseFood` evaluates to `{Orange: "Chicken"}`.

This method of accessing properties is especially useful when you don't know the name of the property you will be changing in advance, as is the case with this code, or when you want to create properties that have names that would otherwise be illegal:

```js
myObj = {
  ".you can't usually use with spaces or start w/ periods": false
};
myObj[".you can't usually use with spaces or start w/ periods"] = true;
console.log(myObj[".you can't usually use with spaces or start w/ periods"]);
// there is no way to read this property the normal way
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is does is:
your object is :

```
var obj = {Orange: "Chicken"};
```

And Your array is :

```
var arr = ['Orange','Lemon','Pork','Chicken']
```

What this line says is pick first element of the array and check for this prop in object and change its value to last element of array, here:

```
arr[0] = "orange";
```

So this line :

`obj[arr[0]]` can be seen as `obj['orange']`.

After that you change its value:

```
Obj[arr[0]] = arr[arr.length-1] which can be written as obj['orange'] = 'chicken'
```